# Using a subdomain to identify a client

Tags: silverlight, web-services, subdomain

I'm working on building a Silverlight application whereas we want to be able to have a client hit a url like:

http://{client}.domain.com/

and login, where the {client} part is their business name.  so for example, google's would be:

http://google.domain.com/

What I was wondering was if anyone has been able, in silverlight, to be able to use this subdomain model to make decisions on the call to the web server so that you can switch to a specific database to run a query?  Unfortunately, it's something that is quite necessary for the project, as we are trying to make it easy for their employees to get their company specific information for our software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it work to put the service on a specific subdomain itself, such as wcf.example.com, and then setup a cross domain policy file on the service to allow it to access it?

As long as this would work you could just load the silverlight in the proper subdomain and then pass that subdomain to your service and let it do its thing.

Some examples of this below:

- [Silverlight Cross Domain Services](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/10/silverlight-services-cross-domain-404-not-found.aspx)
- [Silverlight Cross Domain Policy Helpers](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx)

Comment: awesome.  I thought that the dev guys at Microsoft would have built something similar.  Glad that they did!

I think that will definately work.  We will see.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can check the HTTP 1.1 Host header to see how the user came to your server and do the necessary customization based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this with Silverlight alone, I know you cannot do this without problems with Javascript, Ajax etc. . That is because a sub domain is - for security reasons - treated otherwise than a sub-page by the browsers.

What about the following idea: Insert a rewrite rule to your web server software. So if http://google.domain.com is called, the web server itself rewrites the URL to something like http://www.domain.com/google/ (or better: http://www.domain.com/customers/google/). Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Georgi:

That would help if it would be static, but alas, it's going to all be dynamic.  My hope was to have 1x deployment for the application, and to use the http://google.domain.com/ idea to switch to the correct database for the user.  I recall doing this once when we built an asp.net website, using the domain context to figure out what skin to use, etc.

Ates: Can you explain more about what you are saying... sounds like you are close to what I am trying to come up with.  Have you seen such a tutorial for this?

The only other way I have come up with to make this work is to have a metabase that when the user logs in, it will switch them to the appropriate database as required... was just thinking as well that telling Client x to hit:

http://ClientX.domain.com/ would have been sweeter than saying to hit http://www.domain.com/ and login.  It seemed as if they were to hit their name, and to show it personalized for them right from the login screen would have been much more appealing for the client base.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard B: No, I can't think of any such tutorial that I've seen before. I'll try to be more verbose.

The server-side approach in more detail:

1. Direct *.example.com to the same IP in your DNS settings.
2. The backend app that handles login checks the `Host` HTTP header (e.g. the "HTTP_HOST" server variable in some platforms). That would contain the exact subdomain.example.com that the client used for reaching your server. Extract the subdomain part and continue...

There can also be a client-side-only approach. I don't know much about Silverlight but I'm assuming that you should be able to interface Silverlight with JavaScript. You could read `document.location` with JavaScript and pass it to your Silverlight applet, whereon further data fetching etc. logic would rely on the subdomain that was passed in by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

@Ates:

That is what we did when we wrote the ASP.Net system... we pushed a slew of *.example.com hosts against the web server, and handled using the HTTP headers.  The hold-up comes when dealing with WCF pushing the info between the client and the server... it can only exist in one domain...

So, for example, when you have {client}.example.com and {sandbox}.example.com, the WCF service can't be registered to both.  It also cannot be registered to just *.example.com or example.com, so that's where the catch 22 is coming in at.  everything else I have the prior knowledge of handling.

I recall a method by which an application can "spoof" another domain name in certain instances.  I take it in this case, I would need to do such a configuration?  Much to research yet I believe.